# delete n number of spaces from a line

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep, tr

I am trying to delete n number of spaces between the two words, I was wondering if it’s possible. I searched over the net but couldn't found anything for this. I only find how to delete tab and blank lines.  After I post the question 3 spaces get changet to one, please consider it as three in input.txt.

there are **3 space characters present in between "aaaa" and "bbb" ,I only want to delete two spaces.**

```
$ cat Input.txt
aaaa   bbb   ccc ddd
eeee ff   ggg hhh
```

Desired output:

```
aaaa bbb ccc ddd
eee ff ggg hhh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr` has the `-s` option to squeeze repeated characters:

```
$ tr -s ' ' < file
aaaa bbb ccc ddd
eeee ff ggg hhh
```

> -s, --squeeze-repeats
>
> replace each input sequence of a repeated character that is listed in
>   SET1 with a single occurrence of that character

Another example:

```
$ echo "aaa ----- bbbb ------------- ccc" | tr -s '-'
aaa - bbbb - ccc
```

Answer (score 1):

try these lines, it may help:

```
tr -s ' '
```

or

```
sed 's/ \+/ /g' file
```

or

```
awk '$1=$1' file
```

Comment: `awk '$1=$1'` this is some dangerous, if first field is `0` or `0.0` it will fail.  Its better to use `awk '{$1=$1}1'`

Answer (score 0):

**[Fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19025022/1066031)**'s solution is the best approach but here is how with `sed`:

```
% sed 's/  */ /g' file
aaaa bbb ccc ddd
eeee ff ggg hhh
```